# Checking isLoading state of multiple RTK query mutations to the same endpoint

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I have a single RTK query mutation that the user can initiate several times and with different data. I would like to keep just one reference for the mutation:

```
const [makeRequest, { isLoading }] = someApi.useMutation();
```

I can make multiple `makeRequest(data)` requests, but how can I individually check the state of each request's progress so for eample each button that initiated the request can have their own loading indicator?

### Question

What is the *standard* or *usual* way of handling such situation?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the *standard* or *usual* way of handling such situation?

Honestly the standard way of handling this would be what you are asking *not* to do, which is to have multiple references to the mutation.

Having multiple `useMutation` calls in the same hook can get messy because you wouldn't have a single `isLoading` variable, however you can move the mutation into a sub-component and pass the arguments via props.

> but how can I individually check the state of each request's progress so for example each button that initiated the request can have their own loading indicator?

Here's a little demo showing how we can do that by creating a `RequestButton` component so that each button controls its own loading state.  This keeps the mutation states independent of each other.

```
interface RequestButtonProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  status: string;
}

export default function RequestButton({
  children,
  status
}: RequestButtonProps) {
  const [makeRequest, { isLoading }] = useChangeStatusMutation();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        makeRequest(status);
      }}
    >
      {isLoading ? "loading..." : children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RequestButton status="active">Activate</RequestButton>
      <RequestButton status="inactive">De-activate</RequestButton>
      <RequestButton status="deleted">Delete</RequestButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-calls-to-same-mutation-endpoint-wflw4u?file=/src/App.tsx:46-323)

---

If you want to keep a single `useMutation` hook in the parent component then things get trickier.

We could look at `originalArgs` to see which button triggered the most recent request.

There's a major drawback here: we cannot have multiple buttons in a loading state at once.  As soon as we click one button, the previously "loading..." button will switch to an active state, regardless of the actual query state.

```
export default function App() {
  const [makeRequest, { isLoading, originalArgs }] = useChangeStatusMutation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          makeRequest("active");
        }}
      >
        {isLoading && originalArgs === "active" ? "loading..." : "Activate"}
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          makeRequest("inactive");
        }}
      >
        {isLoading && originalArgs === "inactive"
          ? "loading..."
          : "De-activate"}
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          makeRequest("deleted");
        }}
      >
        {isLoading && originalArgs === "deleted" ? "loading..." : "Delete"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-calls-to-same-mutation-endpoint-forked-z0fps6?file=/src/App.tsx)